# Histogram in JavaFx

Tags: java, graph, javafx, histogram

I have a JavaFX program that displays a histogram to show the occurrences of each letter in a given English text file (not case sensitive).
It should also contain 2 radio buttons, Red and Blue, to change the columns color, and it should also contain a 'draw' button. So it means, your histogram should be empty first, and it can be filled with draw button.
i did the draw button part. I create my columns and add everything i have done to HBox which is hold my screen.

but , i cant doing the radio button part. ıt should change color when i click the 'red' button or 'blue' button. but it did not doing anything.

Here is my code's part which I trouble:

explation: Graph is my chart graph. ıts type is BarChart and also, i create every column using XYChartSeries like that;

XYChartSeries Sutun = new XYChartSeries;

```
    pane = new Pane(); 
    VBox paneforcolorbutton = new VBox(20);
    paneforcolorbutton.setPadding(new Insets(5 ,5 ,5, 5 ));
    paneforcolorbutton.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green;");
    paneforcolorbutton.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 2px ; -fx-border-color: green;");    

    RadioButton blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
    RadioButton red = new RadioButton ("Red");
    paneforcolorbutton.getChildren().addAll(red, blue);

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    red.setToggleGroup(group);
    blue.setToggleGroup(group);

    red.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (red.isSelected()){
            Graph.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill-color: red;");
        }
    });

    blue.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (blue.isSelected()){
            Graph.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill-color: blue;");
        }
    });
```

but it didn't show up in my histogram. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! The question policy on home work states "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please update your question. :)

Comment: I think what they refer to in the guidelines is more "what steps have you taken to try to solve the problem that you ask about here". As in, how have you tried finding out what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @MikaelOhlson using debug. but it didnt gave me anything.

Comment: Hi again thank you for your warnings @MikaelOhlson i did update my question, and i found how i can fix it. here, the right codes;

Answer (score 0):

Hi again thank you for your warnings @MikaelOhlson i did update my question, and i found how i can fix it. here, the right codes;
but here little explation, Graph's type is BarChart and, and i created each column like that;
XYChartSeries Sutun = new XYChartSeries;

```
    VBox paneforcolorbutton = new VBox(); 
    paneforcolorbutton.setPadding(new Insets(20 ,20 ,20, 20 ));  // setting size on it 


    // creating the radio buttons
    RadioButton blue = new RadioButton("Blue"); 
    RadioButton red = new RadioButton ("Red   ");
    paneforcolorbutton.getChildren().addAll(blue, red); // adding them into the paneforcolorbutton vbox 

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup(); 
    red.setToggleGroup(group);
    blue.setToggleGroup(group);

    red.setOnAction((event)->{ // if user clicked the red button, all my charts turn the red
        for(Node n:Graph.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar")) {
            n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: red;");
        }
    });

    blue.setOnAction((event)->{ // if user clicked the blue button, all my charts turn the blue
        for(Node n:Graph.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-bar")) {
            n.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: blue;");
        }
    });
```